# Display data with relationship in Laravel & Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, relational

I'm trying to display data with a relationship (using many-to-many) within my Vue component.

I store users in object from rest API:

```
users: {}, 
//...
axios.get("api/user").then(({data}) => (this.users = data));
```

An example of JSON returned from `api/user`:

```
{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":2,"name":"Andrew","description":"Testing","role":[{"id":2,"role_title":"TestTitle","pivot":{"user_id":2,"role_id":2}}
```

When displaying the data I can do

```
<tr v-for="user in users.data" :key="user.id">
<td>{{user.name}}</td> // DOES work, displays 'Andrew'
```

However if I try to do:

```
<td>{{user.role.role_title}}</td> //does NOT work, should display 'TestTitle'
```

It displays nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user.role` is an array of roles. To display the first role (assuming there will always be at least one role) you can do:

```
<td>{{ user.role[0].role_title }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway I can loop over and display all the roles a given user has? I'm not sure how this is done with the current implementation in Vue.

Comment: Just use `v-for` in the same way you did for each user, but instead for each role.

Comment: Oh, didn't know it was that simple. Thanks!